# swift multiple buttons inside table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How to create view like in image to stretch to all width programmatically

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://cocoapods.org/pods/FlexLayout

I would recommend using something like FlexLayout. It handles laying views out however you determine that you want to lay them out, can handle changing widths, stacking in columns or in rows. Think if it similar to stack views the way you can lay them out. You don't need to use any constraints with this library. (I do not have any connection to the library at all).

Comment: You're right, this layout can solve any complication in layout design. Thanks man